# Reset Identity column to zero in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, identity-column

How can I reset the Identity column of a table to zero in SQL Server?

Edit:

How can we do it with LINQ to SQL ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, NewValue)
```

You can also do a Truncate Table, but, of course, that will remove all rows from the table as well.

To do this via L2S:

```
db.ExecuteCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('MyTable', RESEED, NewValue);");
```

Or, you can call a stored procedure, from L2S, to do it

Comment: How can we do it with LINQ to SQL ?

Comment: Thanks dude, But I have a problem in executing the above command. I've choose a name for my table in UTF-8 format(Persian) and then I insert it instead of `MyTable` the following error is occurred `Cannot find a table or object with the name "[????? ?????? ???]". Check the system catalog.` How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 9):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( ‘databasename.dbo.yourtable’,RESEED, 0)
```

More info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Comment: How can we do it with LINQ to SQL ?

Comment: @Mohammad: execute that SQL statement with `context.ExecuteCommand`

Answer (score 6):

Use the LINQ to SQL ExecuteCommand to run the required SQL.

```
db.ExecuteCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', RESEED, 0);");
```

LINQ is a data-source agnostic query language and has no built-in facilities for this kind of data-source specific functionality. LINQ to SQL doesn't provide a specific function to do this either AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(‘tableName’, RESEED, 0)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything that wasn't already contained in the previous answers, please consider deleting.

Answer (score 3):

Generic extension method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Reseeds a table's identity auto increment to a specified value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The row type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TIdentity">The type of the identity column</typeparam>
    /// <param name="table">The table to reseed</param>
    /// <param name="seed">The new seed value</param>
    public static void ReseedIdentity<TEntity, TIdentity>(this Table<TEntity> table, TIdentity seed)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var rowType = table.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var sqlCommand = string.Format(
            "dbcc checkident ('{0}', reseed, {1})",
            table.Context.Mapping.GetTable(rowType).TableName, 
            seed);

        table.Context.ExecuteCommand(sqlCommand);
    }
```

Usage: `myContext.myTable.ReseedIdentity(0);`

Comment: Is TIdentity necessary?

Comment: You saved my day dude. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the same task in a SQL Compact table use:

```
db.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN Id IDENTITY (1,1)";   
db.ExecuteNonQuery(  );
```